# reload page after back button but keep scroll position

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am writing a simple PHP Ajax CRUD.
After editing data for a row in edit.php, I hit Go back button with window.history.back();

The data is updated on MySQL but the main list (after go back) wasn't updated.
I guess I should use reload() but if I use that, whenever the page is reloaded, the scroll position will jump to top, which is not so convenient for users.

I searched some solutions that store scroll position to a local storage then call it back after reloading, but I have no idea where to start with. Any idea for this?

Comment: You can use HTML anchor link: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html

Comment: thanks but the anchor link would scroll the page to top of a row, while I want it to be exactly previous location

Answer (score 1):

Use GET parameters to save the position of your scroll, while still refreshing:

```
var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop; // get page scroll
location.href = '?scroll=' + scroll; // refresh page and save scroll as a GET parameter
```

And add this somewhere at the beginning of your script (so you can check to see if a `scroll` parameter is set and scroll to that position):

```
// get scroll parameter
var scrollFromGet = location.search.match(/scroll=(\d+)/);

// set scroll if there is any
if(scrollFromGet[1]) 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollFromGet[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.
The page when use window.history.back(); is not updated. Then we need to reload it whenever it is navigated back by window.history.back();
Otherwise, it will be loaded only once.

Here is the solution: [LINK](https://www.mrc-productivity.com/techblog/?p=1235)

So by reloading it self, most browser will keep the same scroll y as before. So I'm good to go